# What should I put in the href when I prototype?

Tags: html, prototyping

When protyping we often do empty anchors. A very common way to do this is to do something like:

```
<a href="#">Go here</a>
```

But if the client clicks this link, the page will scroll to the top. But if we leave out the href attribute, the link won't behave like a link.

I've see stuff like:

```
<a href="javascript;">Go here</a>
```

But it doesn't look right.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Go here</a>
```

will do nothing when you click on it. i think the 'standard' is to just use a # though and tell the client that it's a prototype and so links will not function properly :)

Comment: isnt there any shorter syntax to accomplish the same effect?

Comment: possibly `<a href="javascript;">Go here</a>` would work too, but you already stated that :)